# How can I change the sprites in the NES Double Dragon ROM?

Tags: modding, roms

I have played a few NES ROMs where people have gone into them and changed the sprites. How did they do this?

I'd like to do this for the Double Dragon ROM. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Narrow the scope of your question. You're asking for software to create a mod, how to create a mod in general and what the legality is. Tell us what you've done already and what's not working. Starting from zero is a really broad way to ask a question.

Comment: I am at zero right now.  I have no experience with modding, but I have done plenty of photo editing.  I'm guessing I just need a program to unpack the images from an existing mod, and then re-pack them after the edits are done.

Comment: Not all cartridges used the same format for storing image data. What game are you trying to mod?

Comment: Simpsons Double dragon

Comment: Check out these utilities: http://www.zophar.net/utilities/nesgraph.html

Comment: Have a look at http://www.romhacking.net. They have tutorials, forums, tools and even more. This is probably what you need.

Comment: @VaughanHilts Shouldn't you post that link as an answer?

Comment: @HugoRocha Link only answers are not welcome here.

Comment: Then the link with an explanation of the tool? :)

Comment: Sure, its the best one so far

Answer (score 2):

Just to extract an answer from the comments:

[Zophars Domain](http://www.zophar.net/utilities/nesgraph.html) shows you a list of tools that you can use for NES ROMs including [Graphics Extractor and Inserter](http://www.zophar.net/utilities/nesgraph/graphics-extractor-and-inserter.html) which allows you to extract and insert tile graphics from the ROM.

To use this you need the Extractor executable and the Inserter. Use the extractor to get the tiles first, edit them in your editor of choice (MS Paint ftw) and then use the inserter to pop them back into the ROM. Make sure you create a backup in-case it corrupts the ROM image.